# How can I see the value of a terraform module that is creating multiples resources?

Tags: amazon-s3, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am using a terraform module to create s3 buckets and the code I have inherited uses a list of bucket names as a variable and essentially loops through the s3_bucket_names variable creating a bucket for_each name in the list.

The problem arises when I need to call the id from one of these created buckets to set up an s3_notification_event on a specific bucket. I understand if this was a single bucket or each bucket was called individually with its own module resource I could return the single id with a module.aws_s3_bucket.data_bucket.id output call, for example.

I know I can rewrite the script and call the module individually which would resolve the issue but does anyone know how to return the values of a specific resource when looping through a single module?

For reference:

```
module "aws_s3_bucket" {
  source               = "****"
  s3_bucket_names      = var.s3_bucket_names
  s3_bucket_acl        = var.s3_bucket_acl
  versioning           = var.versioning
  s3_log_target_bucket = var.s3_log_target_bucket
  s3_log_prefix        = var.s3_log_prefix
}
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  for_each = var.s3_bucket_names
  ...
}
```

Thanks for any advice/insight anyone can provide.

Comment: What are the outputs from your `aws_s3_bucket` module?

Comment: I am not particularly sure what to put to get this value. I inherited the following output:
`
output "s3_bucket_names" {
  value = ["${module.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_names}"]
}
`

As mentioned in the initial comment, if I was calling the module each time for each bucket, I could call the specific value using:
'
output "s3_bucket_id" {
  value = ["${module.aws_s3_bucket.data_bucket.id}"]
}
`